How to Preventing Cracks in Mutton Seekh Kebabs in tandoor
My mutton seekh kebabs were cracking in the tandoor. How much fat should I use in the seekh mixture? I Googled it and they say 20 to 30 percent fat. I think that amount of fat is high for seekh kebabs.

Howdy!  To get a good answer to your question, it would help if you pasted or linked to a recipe similar to the one you're using.
